# SQL Server Advice for an old hack

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Evening guys and gals, I am hoping some of you legends might be able to be help me out here :)

I last used SQL Server back on version 7 back in the dark ages (we rubbed two sticks together to get it going). Now here I am in in the 21st century and would like to come back to DBA work again.

I would like to setup a 'cheap' virtual machine & instance to play with, then work towards the newest certification (I see the newest will commence April 2017 which is good timing for me I think). I am particularly interested in the BI side of things.

Can anyone recommend a good hosting provider for a virtual machine? Do I simply get a Windows Server and go from there or can I get a package somewhere? Azure I assume or elsewhere? I suspect there are a number of options, hoping you can share some good ones :)

Plus any other helpful tips are most welcome, cheers!

Comment: noted! it was my first question guys

Answer (score 14):

The easiest solution is actually free: [Microsoft's Virtual Labs.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/virtual-labs) You get access to SQL Servers in the cloud, plus step-by-step instructions on what to experiment with. (You aren't required to do their tutorials, either - you can use the VMs for anything you like.)

Keep in mind that there's a few restrictions: you can't surf the web from there, and you can't copy/paste things in. Because of that, it's a little limited - but you can't beat free.

If you're going to run your own SQL Server, I wouldn't recommend doing it in the cloud since you pay by the hour. You're better off using a free virtualization tool like Hyper-V, ESXi, or VirtualBox, and then installing the totally free [SQL Server Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-developers). Good luck on your learning journey!

Answer (score 4):

Brent noted on it in his answer but just to expand a bit more...I'll just note around learning the BI side of things that using Azure (or other cloud providers) may get a bit expensive. You will need a minimum server size to truly work with those components and running those (or forgetting to turn them off) can drive your bill up rather quickly. [e.g I've forgot to turn one server off and it ran for a day or so, had a bill for about $40.]

Now that is not to say that you should shy away from doing anything in the cloud. With Azure you can get a $25 credit each month from [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/), same place where you download free Dev Edition of SQL Server. While it is not much to do things for days at a time, it will at least get you familiar with that side of the DBA/BI world.

I actually do most of my learning with BI locally on my laptop, just have local SQL Server instance installed and then Visual Studio 2015 + SSDT. (VS 2015 is current version of this writing.). I play around with data sets [I download from Internet](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/) and just load them into a database...then you can play with designing SSRS report around it. You also have the [data dump from StackExchange](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) to use as well, which was just updated a few months ago.

Comment: Another excellent and helpful answer! You guys rock! (and possiblyalso roll)